# Why does the output differ when input "i" instead of "j" as the key in HashMap?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, hashmap

I am using 2 for loops as below to get the sum of the numbers in an int[]. getTotal() is suppose to give the sum of the values in array which are below 100. The sum is calculated by adding the values one by one until it exceeds hundred. When it exceeds hundred it starts again with the next value and adds one by one like before.

```
private static HashMap<Integer,Integer> getTotal(){
    int total = 0;
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> finalTotal = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        total += array.get(i);
        for (int j = i+1; j < array.length; j++) {
            if(total>100){
                finalTotal.put(j,total - array.get(j));
                total = 0;
            }
            else if(total<100){
                total += array.get(j);
            }
        }
    }
    return finalTotal;
}
```

When printing the result in the hash-map it gives 2 different maps of answers when I use i and j for as the key. Isn't it suppose to give the same values and just different keys as answers? Not only the value the amount length of the hashmap also changes.

It would be great if you could point out any mistakes and explain why this happens.

Comment: What is `array`? The syntax for array seems wrong. You use `length` and the `get()`. Is it a list or an actual array?

Comment: Sorry, it is arrayLength not array.length and array is the name of the int[]

Comment: This code is unreadable (at a glance) without comments or context, what is it trying to accomplish?

Comment: 'when I use i and j for as the key' the key for the hashmap, or the index of the array?

Comment: Each `put` can overwrite an earlier `put` with the same key.  Probably, the value of `j` at which you do a `put` coincided with the value of `j` at an earlier `put`, causing you to lose the total from the earlier `put`.  If you really want to know what's going on, you should step through this with your debugger.

Comment: Why do you think it should be the same? Do both even make sense? It doesn't appear so.

Comment: It would be the same if each `put` used a distinct key, since the values being `put` will be the same, regardless of the key.  But this code could easily create a situation where key values are the same, from one `put` to the next - hence the difference in what values end up in the map.  @user207421

Comment: @DawoodsaysreinstateMonica I'm asking the OP to explain himself, not you to explain what we can all see for ourselves.

Comment: @DawoodsaysreinstateMonica You're missing the point. I asked the question for a reason, and it isn't because I don't know the answer. It's the OP who needs to do the thinking here, and the explaining.

Comment: I fixed it. the problem was that when i put "j" as the key the value gets overwrite cause there are more than one instance that the last value it adds is being "J". @DawoodsaysreinstateMonica it was the issue as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying your code, for smaller numbers for examples sake

```
//*******************************************************************
// Welcome to CompileJava!
// If you experience any issues, please contact us ('More Info')  -->
//*******************************************************************

import java.lang.Math; // headers MUST be above the first class
import java.util.HashMap;

// one class needs to have a main() method
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
  // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    System.out.println(getTotal());
  }


  private static HashMap<Integer,Integer> getTotal(){
    int total = 0;
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> finalTotal = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        total += array[i];
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("//i = " + i + "; arr[i] = " + array[i]);
        System.out.println("total += " + array[i] + "; // total = " + total);
        for (int j = i+1; j < array.length; j++) {
            System.out.println("    //j = " + j + "; arr[j] = " + array[j]);
            if(total>5){
                finalTotal.put(j,total - array[j]);
                System.out.println("    finalTotal += (" + j+", "+total + "-" + array[j]+")");
                total = 0;
            }
            else if(total<5){
                total += array[j];
                System.out.println("    total += " + array[j]+"; //total = "+total);
            }
        }
    }
    return finalTotal;
  }
}
```

Stepping through your code, and recording the results gives

```
//i = 0; arr[i] = 1
total += 1; // total = 1
    //j = 1; arr[j] = 2
    total += 2; //total = 3
    //j = 2; arr[j] = 3
    total += 3; //total = 6
    //j = 3; arr[j] = 4
    finalTotal += (3, 6-4)
    //j = 4; arr[j] = 5
    total += 5; //total = 5
    //j = 5; arr[j] = 6
    //j = 6; arr[j] = 7
    //j = 7; arr[j] = 8
    //j = 8; arr[j] = 9
    //j = 9; arr[j] = 10

//i = 1; arr[i] = 2
total += 2; // total = 7
    //j = 2; arr[j] = 3
    finalTotal += (2, 7-3)
    //j = 3; arr[j] = 4
    total += 4; //total = 4
    //j = 4; arr[j] = 5
    total += 5; //total = 9
    //j = 5; arr[j] = 6
    finalTotal += (5, 9-6)
    //j = 6; arr[j] = 7
    total += 7; //total = 7
    //j = 7; arr[j] = 8
    finalTotal += (7, 7-8)
    //j = 8; arr[j] = 9
    total += 9; //total = 9
    //j = 9; arr[j] = 10
    finalTotal += (9, 9-10)

//i = 2; arr[i] = 3
total += 3; // total = 3
    //j = 3; arr[j] = 4
    total += 4; //total = 7
    //j = 4; arr[j] = 5
    finalTotal += (4, 7-5)
    //j = 5; arr[j] = 6
    total += 6; //total = 6
    //j = 6; arr[j] = 7
    finalTotal += (6, 6-7)
    //j = 7; arr[j] = 8
    total += 8; //total = 8
    //j = 8; arr[j] = 9
    finalTotal += (8, 8-9)
    //j = 9; arr[j] = 10
    total += 10; //total = 10

//i = 3; arr[i] = 4
total += 4; // total = 14
    //j = 4; arr[j] = 5
    finalTotal += (4, 14-5)
    //j = 5; arr[j] = 6
    total += 6; //total = 6
    //j = 6; arr[j] = 7
    finalTotal += (6, 6-7)
    //j = 7; arr[j] = 8
    total += 8; //total = 8
    //j = 8; arr[j] = 9
    finalTotal += (8, 8-9)
    //j = 9; arr[j] = 10
    total += 10; //total = 10

//i = 4; arr[i] = 5
total += 5; // total = 15
    //j = 5; arr[j] = 6
    finalTotal += (5, 15-6)
    //j = 6; arr[j] = 7
    total += 7; //total = 7
    //j = 7; arr[j] = 8
    finalTotal += (7, 7-8)
    //j = 8; arr[j] = 9
    total += 9; //total = 9
    //j = 9; arr[j] = 10
    finalTotal += (9, 9-10)

//i = 5; arr[i] = 6
total += 6; // total = 6
    //j = 6; arr[j] = 7
    finalTotal += (6, 6-7)
    //j = 7; arr[j] = 8
    total += 8; //total = 8
    //j = 8; arr[j] = 9
    finalTotal += (8, 8-9)
    //j = 9; arr[j] = 10
    total += 10; //total = 10

//i = 6; arr[i] = 7
total += 7; // total = 17
    //j = 7; arr[j] = 8
    finalTotal += (7, 17-8)
    //j = 8; arr[j] = 9
    total += 9; //total = 9
    //j = 9; arr[j] = 10
    finalTotal += (9, 9-10)

//i = 7; arr[i] = 8
total += 8; // total = 8
    //j = 8; arr[j] = 9
    finalTotal += (8, 8-9)
    //j = 9; arr[j] = 10
    total += 10; //total = 10

//i = 8; arr[i] = 9
total += 9; // total = 19
    //j = 9; arr[j] = 10
    finalTotal += (9, 19-10)

//i = 9; arr[i] = 10
total += 10; // total = 10
{2=4, 3=2, 4=9, 5=9, 6=-1, 7=9, 8=-1, 9=9}
```

This is only a few steps in, and it really doesn't seem like it does anything like you asked. I recommend looking up how to use a debugger, and step through your code.

Notice that j is not the same thing as arr[j]

Notice that loops within loops, still loop, and take care of the start positions of the loop.

Hashmaps will update their value, should you insert a duplicate, given your code (note that you don't handle the case where total==5/100, loop enough times and it's bound to happen) and you will get differing values.

Start on smaller problems / inputs that you are able to debug , and work your way up.

Answer (score -1):

You need to define `array` before using it.

Comment: As the code executes and prints a result clearly this is not the problem.